# event.srcElement is null in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

We are using asp.net webforms.
Server is generating input element (image) with `onclick` event.
When click occurs I'm calling function and passing event object into it.

Inside that function I am trying to access `event.srcElement.className` to get the class name of the element that caused the event.
Only in IE8 event's `srcElement` is null.

What would be the possible solution to this problem?

How can I get the class name of the element that caused the click event inside the function that is called when event occurs?

Selected answer solves my problem but doesn't answer the question!

Comment: You're sure that `srcElement` is null and not `event` for some reason? Such as not passing/handling the `event` object properly when the event occurs?

Comment: yes, I debugged it in IE8 the event object is there but srcElement is null. I used event object to calculate mouse cursor position in a way that jquery does it since the content is auto-generated and couldn't do jquery stuff so easily.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use jQuery library wich would help with cross browser issues. Using jQuery you could use event.target and all of it's properties. Problem to this is inconsistent DOM API across various browsers.

In jQuery you could do like this:

```
$(selector).click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.className);
    console.log(event.target.classList);
});
```

Comment: I tried to avoid using jQuery for this since content is dynamically generated, including class names, onclick event etc. I'm 101% using jQuery for this kind of stuff in the future. In this case it would not be that straight forward but it is doable with some additional logic in $(document).ready(); and conditional event binding. For now, my workaround was to pass generated class name itself to the function that is called and to ignore event handling since I don't have much time to finish this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: jQuery can and will do everything what you want, just even better and faster. I still don't understand why would someone want to use native DOM API. It sucks and it will continue to suck and for that reason it's not smart to use it directly and it is better to rely on libraries like jQuery

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the `event`, just pass the clicked element to the `javascript` function.

```
<input type="button" onclick="func(this)" value="Ok" class="myClass"/>
```

Then directly access the element's style class.

```
<script>
    function func(elem) {
        alert(elem.className);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that, what I did was to add additional parameter to a function call and pass element's dynamically generated class name to that function. Thanks for the answer.